# How do I rename files with bash script in a particular folder

Tags: bash, shell, file-rename

Here is my script I'm using and is not getting the job done

```
 cp -rv app/build/outputs/apk/!(*unaligned*).apk  output/

   #rename file after copy

   for file in *.apk;
   do
   mv "$file" "$name-$appName".apk
   done
```

Basically I want to copy all file from one folder to another and then rename all of them, the copy works fine.

The current name of the file is with underscore(_) but I want to rename the using (-) dash.

original file: `name_appName_1.0_debug.apk`

Expected result : `name-appName-1.0-debug.apk`

I'm not really great with regex, because when I run this same script on my mac it worked fine, but I'm doing this on my build server.

Comment: `ychaouche@ychaouche-PC 17:20:08 ~/DOWNLOADS/WEB $ echo name_appName_1.0_debug.apk | sed 's/_/-/g'
name-appName-1.0-debug.apk
ychaouche@ychaouche-PC 17:20:31 ~/DOWNLOADS/WEB $ 
` Doesn't look great in the comment because I can't add newlines, or so it seems. But the last `name-appName-1.0-debug.apk` was the output of the sed command. You could use it in your bash for loop.

Comment: so can I use something like this $ echo name_appName_1.0_debug.apk | sed 's/_/-/g' name-appName-1.0-debug.apk in place of the mv  cmd the problem is something I might not know the name of the file, but the naming converntion will be the same but at the end I want to rename the files to my expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the renaming quickly using `find` and `rename`.

After your `cp` line:

```
find output/ -execdir rename 's/_/-/g' '{}' \+
```

find will recursively work through whatever is in the directory `output` and will pass whatever it finds to rename. The expression there is super simple and really just breaks down to `s/<the thing to replace>/<what it will be replaced with/g` The `g` at the end says replace all occurences. Omitting the `g` will just replace the first occurrence in the filename. The `{}` is the token for whatever `find` finds.

Comment: will that preserve the ext(.apk)?

Comment: Extensions are just part of the file name. Linux is nothing like Windows in how windows treats extensions as sacrosanct. The `rename` `s/_/-/g` will only swap out underscores with hyphens and leave everything else intact.

Comment: Cool, what if I want to add more string to the output, sorry I missed that in the initail question. Expected result : name-appName-1.0-debug-pro-online.apk

Comment: What does "More strings to the output" mean.. Like if you wanted to replace every underscore with the '-poop-', it would look like `s/_/-poop-/g`

Comment: here is the original file: name_appName_1.0_debug.apk but I want something different like free_version_appname_1.0_pro.apk